# Why does Stream#findAny() exist?

Tags: java, java-stream

I don't know exactly how Streams work internally, but I have always wondered why `Stream#findAny()` exists, when there is `Stream#findFirst()`. Find *first* suggests that streams keep the order of the array/`Collection`/`Iterator` from which they are created. So why use any? If it is irrelevant which element you are getting, it may as well be the first one. From what I'm thinking, `findFirst` should always execute in constant time.

The Javadoc of `Stream#findAny()` states:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic; it is
> free to select any element in the stream. This is to allow for
> maximal performance in parallel operations; the cost is that multiple
> invocations on the same source may not return the same result. (If a
> stable result is desired, use {@link #findFirst()} instead.)

But even then isn't the order of elements known? The provided datastructure stays the same.

Comment: A stream wasn't necessarily created from an ordered input or it might be faster to execute some intermediate step in a non-deterministic way. If the pipeline knows you don't care about *specifically* finding the first result, it might be able to optimize the processing.

Comment: Take a stream of two elements and process them to get a result. The first takes 400 years to complete. The second 1 minute. `findFirst` will wait the whole *400 years* to return the first elements result. While `findAny` will return the second result after 1 minute. See the difference? Depending on the circumstances of what exactly you're doing, you just want the fastest result, and don't care about the order.

Comment: So this can only happen in parallell streams? In a sequential stream there should be no way of knowing how long an operation will take, right?

Comment: @xtay2 the javadoc you've shown also mentions that part: *This is to allow for maximal performance in **parallel** operations;*. In a sequential stream I'm assuming it behaves the same as `findFirst()`

Comment: It is an implementing thing: **parallel** is evidently. But also before **sorted** is completed `findAny` could be successful (consider the filtering is applied _before_ sorting); unlikely sorted+findAny is. _I did not inspect the sources._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Stream#findAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) is used it when we're looking for an element without paying an attention to the encounter order.

Comment from [Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino) at the time of answer which correctly summarizes the difference:

> Take a stream of two elements and process them to get a result. The
> first takes 400 years to complete. The second 1 minute. `findFirst` will
> wait the whole 400 years to return the first elements result. While
> `findAny` will return the second result after 1 minute. See the
> difference? Depending on the circumstances of what exactly you're
> doing, you just want the fastest result, and don't care about the
> order.

Consider this code for `findFirst`:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Optional<Integer> result = list
                           .stream()
                           .filter(num -> num < 4)
                           .findFirst();              // .findAny();
```

Here, `findAny` operates as `findFirst`, still not guarantee. **On my machine, after 10 odd runs, The output is always `1` though.**

Now, let's consider a parallel stream, for which `findAny` is designed for:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Optional<Integer> result = list
                           .stream()
                           .parallel()
                           .filter(num -> num < 4)
                           .findAny();
```

Now the output on my machine `3`. But it could be anything `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Let's do some benchmarking with inputs favoring `findAny` (i.e. the predicate should be true after the middle of the stream).

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

long findFirstStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    list.stream().filter(num -> num > 500000).findFirst();
}
long findFirstEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long findAnyStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    list.stream().parallel().filter(num -> num > 500000).findAny();
}
long findAnyEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("findFirst time taken: " + (findFirstEndTime - findFirstStartTime));
System.out.println("findAny time taken: "   + (findAnyEndTime - findAnyStartTime));
```

`findFirst` will go sequentially, till the middle of the stream and `findAny` will go as the almighty wants. The results are staggering:

```
findFirst time taken: 29324
findAny time taken: 623
```

---

Using [JMH Benchmarking](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) with params:

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)

Benchmark          Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
FindAny.findAny    avgt   50   191700.823 ± 251565.289  ns/op
FindAny.findFirst  avgt   50  4157585.786 ± 355005.501  ns/op
```

Comment: While the answer displays everthing relevant (and correct!). I would be careful when using a simple benchmark like yours. You might be running into some problems that favor one result over the other. Like said in this other question: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)